# How to read the next element with find_all

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup

First I want to thank you if you take a look at my post. I found many posts about how to read the next element using BS4 but it was concerning problem where keywords were relevant.

Here is my issue: I try to scrap data from txt.files and the way the HTML is build has a similar environment for different variables.

For instance here is one of the variable I want to extract :

(do not pay attention to the encode/decode part)

```
    number= bs.find_all('span', class_='grid_1 prefix_1 suffix_1 data')[0].get_text().encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode(
    'ascii')
```

It works well but now the next variable I want to extract which appears after the *number* has exactly the same html build. So when I run

```
Local= bs.find_all('span', class_=''span', class_='grid_1 prefix_1 suffix_1 data')[0].get_text().encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode(
    'ascii')
number= bs.find_all('span', class_='grid_1 prefix_1 suffix_1 data')[0].get_text().encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode(
    'ascii')
```

It gives me the same information for the two variables. I understand that BS4 stops to the first time he meets the elements inserted in the findall.

After reading Beautiful Soup Documentation I try to use the find_next command to have the data corresponding to the 2nd element.
When I run:

```
    Local= bs.find_all('span', class_='grid_1 prefix_1 suffix_1 data')[0].find_all_next().encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode(
    'ascii')
```

I get the following Python Error:
**AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute**

And when I try to run the find_next command alone as follow:

```
Local= bs.find_next('span', class_='grid_1 prefix_1 suffix_1 data')[0].encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode(
    'ascii')
```

I get the following Python Error:
**TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'**

My question is "How to apply correctly the find_next command to the find_all?"

Answer (score 0):

The `find_all()` function returns all the `span` tags that match your given `class` parameter: `class_='grid_1 prefix_1 suffix_1 data'`

So, there is no "next" element to find. You already have it.

Try looping over the results from `find_all()`:

```
spans = bs.find_all('span', class_='grid_1 prefix_1 suffix_1 data')
for span in spans:
    sub_text = re.sub(r'[\ \n\r]{2,}', '', span.get_text())
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer I understand well why I've these errors but when I run the code you proposed I've the following error **IndentationError: unexpected indent**

Comment: Check your whitespace formatting, if you cut and pasted the code there may be a mix of spaces/tabs.